# c# IEnumerable DataRow int field casting issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, exception, oracle11g, casting

We have an application compatible with both Oracle and MsSql dbs. LocationId field is `<int>` in MsSql db and `<number(10,0)>` in Oracle db. When I cast below locationId in the code to `Int32`, it works on MsSql environment and throws exception in Oracle. When I cast it to `Int64`, then it works for Oracle and throws "invalid cast exception" in MsSql env. I know I can handle this. But I am wondering is there a better way to overcome this issue by casting another type which can handle both. Any suggestion is appreciated. thx.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> dataTableByLoc = 
      from rowsByLoc in dTable.AsEnumerable()
       where rowsByLoc.Field<Int32>("locationID") == nextLocInfo.getLocationId()
      select rowsByLoc;
```

ERROR:

```
16-02-2017 15:24:06 ERROR [MFES.Log] Error running export    at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at MFES.Plugins.GYG.DailyExports.GYGDailyExportMain.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<exportTableByLocation>b__0(DataRow rowsByLocation)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I am not sure of the exact solution of this problem but you can avoid it. Is Any particular reason you need to do AsEnumerable ? You can filter the table by using  `Select` method on DataTable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx This will give you array of filtered rows.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for the alternative. I am a java developer and has a good but not very deep knowledge on c#. This method did not come up in my searches while browsing. Thanks for your comment, that worked well. dont know how to credit your comment.let me know.

Comment: I am glad that your issue is resoved. No worries about the credit.  Happy coding!!!!